# COMMIT TRAN & EXEC stored procedure printing values in the result window

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Perl client and a SQL Server database to handle data operations. I have written a stored procedure on the server that in turn calls another stored procedure and uses atomic operations such as `COMMIT TRAN` and `ROLLBACK TRAN`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProc
    @SignatureID = NULL,      --//Always valid params are passed while executing
    @DebugIssueID INT = NULL,
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   CREATE TABLE #TempTable
   (
       --// 2 INT Columns
   )

   IF @BooleanCondition
   BEGIN
     BEGIN TRAN
     -- //many things before calling the other stored procedure below
     EXEC UpdateDebugIssueStoredProc
           @SignatureID = @SignatureID ,
           @DebugIssueID = @DebugIssueID 

     --//Some code that inserts many rows into #TempTable

     --//Finally committing the transaction
     IF @@ERROR = 0
        COMMIT TRAN
     ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRAN
   END

   SELECT * FROM #TempTable
END
```

I only want result set returned by #TempTable. However when I execute `MyStoredProc` with one set of params, my results print looks  [as seen in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKGjr.png). After debugging and stepping through, I found that, it prints `DebugIssueID` returned by `EXEC UpdateDebugIssueStoredProc`. Since `UpdateDebugIssueStoredProc` is written by someone else, I cannot edit that.

So I tried catching the value in a dummy variable to avoid the result printing as follows, but it didn't change the results printed.

```
EXEC @DummyVariable = UpdateDebugIssueStoredProc
       @SignatureID = @SignatureID ,
       @DebugIssueID = DebugIssueID
```

Similarly, it prints a `1` (or zero) returned by `COMMIT TRAN` (as shown in the screenshot) followed by resultset in the `#TempTable`.

I believe, the following error, is due to above printing/result-returning stuff. Client seems to throw the following error since it is not written to catch anything other than the intended result set.

> DBD::ODBC::st execute failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (SQL-HY000) Died at MyScript.pl line 256,  DBD::ODBC::st fetchrow_array warning: no select statement currently executing

Comment: If you want to change the behaviour of the SP, you need to `ALTER` the SP; there's not a lot else we can really suggest there. otherwise you'll need to get your application to read the third result set.

Comment: As you already have set nocount on, that means the printing of the values by  UpdateDebugIssueStoredProc is due to a explicit print statement which you will have to alter.

Comment: Could I, at least, stop printing 1 or 0 returned by COMMIT TRAN ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't print the results only select.

And how wrote @larnu you need to change the procedure or your application's behavior.